# How much memory is used to create a Div in a web page?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to figure out roughly how much a div, with some amount of content (nested divs perhaps), would take up in memory.

How would I even go about figuring this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a little javascript that creates 100, 500, 1000, etc divs depending on which option is selected.  Check the memory usage of the browser before and after selecting your option and divide by the number of div's you created.  Try to use really large numbers of divs to get a better average, and be sure to test on different browsers, different versions, and different platforms.

Answer (score 1):

It varies per browser, but there really shouldn't be any need to know tiny details like this. Why do you need to know?

If you really want to know the internals of the browsers, (the open source ones at least) crack open the source. For a `div` element in Firefox, I found [this file](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/content/html/content/src/nsHTMLDivElement.cpp), and I bet you can find others.

Comment: wondering how many divs can be displayed without using too much memory

Comment: @Joda: If you have enough `div`s in which that becomes a problem, maybe try to implement pagination with a reasonable default?

Comment: @Joda, that limit is going to depend a lot on other factors like what sorts of styles are applied, and if JavaScript is running (and if so, what's happening in the script). Simply displaying static, unstyled `<div>`s itself isn't particularly memory-intensive.

Answer (score -1):

Its Size..! Do this--> Make 100,1000 divs , add style all. Go to your network tab in your browser console and look at the size usage. Similarly do it for images. You will understand the difference.! At core pixel manipulation of image as CCD array is bit costly than straight forward pixel array of divs.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. You can have a 20mb image that performs well when rendered in a 20x20px area (as an example). On the other hand you can also have a 2mb HTML page with tonnes of elements that easily crashes the browser.